# SQL stored procedure to convert a blob field to XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, zip, compression

I have an xml file stored in the DB. this xml file is converted to a  zipped byte[]  and then stored in the db as shown below:

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = null;
 ZipOutputStream out = null;
 try {
     byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     out = new ZipOutputStream(byteOut);
     out.setLevel(level);      
      ZipInput entry = new ZipStringInput("string", xmlString));
      out.putNextEntry(getZipEntry(encrypt, entry.getEntryName()));
        InputStream in = entry.getInputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER];
        for (int length; (length = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
     out.finish();
     saveToDB(byteOut.toByteArray()
```

In java I can easily fetch it like shown below (simplified wihtout catch, close etc.,):

```
byte[] xmlBytes = (byte[])blob;
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlBytes );) {
    try (ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(byteIn);) {          
        for (ZipEntry entry; (entry = zipIn.getNextEntry()) != null;) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
            for (int length; (length = zipIn.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1;) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);                       
            }
        }
        return out.toString("UTF-8"));
}
```

Oracle DB: Now I have to task to do the same in a SQL stored procedure. how do I do it. I have tried combinations of lz_uncompress, lob.substr etc., I can see the bytes, but not sure how to convert it to the XML file.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE print_clob AS
v_clob    CLOB;
v_varchar VARCHAR2(32767);
v_start   PLS_INTEGER := 1;
v_buffer  PLS_INTEGER := 32767;
blob_in   BLOB;
x         XMLTYPE;
BEGIN
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_clob, true);
    FOR i IN (
        SELECT
            blobdata AS blob_in
        FROM
            myTable
        WHERE
            id = 123
    ) LOOP
        FOR j IN 1..ceil(dbms_lob.getlength(i.blob_in) / v_buffer) LOOP
            v_varchar := dbms_lob.substr(i.blob_in, v_buffer, v_start);                 
            dbms_lob.writeappend(v_clob, length(v_varchar), v_varchar);
            v_start := v_start + v_buffer;
        END LOOP; 
        dbms_output.put_line(v_clob ); prints some binary stirng looking like '504B0304140008000800E0843E4200000000000000000.....'
      --  dbms_output.put_line(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NVARCHAR2(v_clob )); -> throws  error
      --  dbms_output.put_line(utl_compress.lz_uncompress(v_clob )); -> throws  error  
        --x := xmltype.createxml(v_clob); -> Throws error that the input it not an XML <, but some randoms tring
     --   dbms_output.put_line(x.getclobval());
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to substring a BLOB and stick it into a CLOB without any conversion. If the BLOB is compressed, you'll need to uncompress it first with `utl_compress.lz_uncompress`. Then once uncompressed, you need to convert it to a CLOB using `dbms_lob.converttoclob`.

Comment: Hi Paul, before putting into the clob, I have tried uncompress on v_varchar, i get the error: Verify that source data is a valid compressed or uncompressed
           data set.

Comment: v_varchar := utl_compress.lz_uncompress(dbms_lob.substr(i.blob_in, v_buffer, v_start));  
 dbms_lob.writeappend(v_clob, length(v_varchar), v_varchar;
-> throws error "Verify that source data is a valid compressed or uncompressed data set"

Comment: when using converttoclob, i got the error:  PLS-00222: no function with name 'CONVERTTOCLOB' exists in this scope

Comment: lz_uncompress takes a BLOB and returns a BLOB. You can't assign its output to a CLOB. I also wouldn't attempt to substring a BLOB - it's a binary object, not something you can simply split at an arbitrary point. Uncompress the entire BLOB and assign it to another BLOB. Then pass that uncompressed binary value into the dbms_lob.converttoclob function, which will pass back the readable CLOB via the dest_lob out parameter. Note the package name dbms_lob before the function name. See the documentation on these functions.

Comment: thats the very first thing I tried: select utl_compress.lz_uncompress(xml_blob)  from mytable where id=123; -> same error. I had also tried to get the entire blob and then tried uncompress. same error. The dbms_lob.convertoclob is just avavilable in the sqldeveloper.

Comment: url_compress procedures handle simple (un-) compression of a stream of bytes, a ZIP file is more than that: it contains header with meta-data...

Comment: You're trying to decompress something zipped outside the database?  That will only work if it's using the same compression algorithm. From Oracle docs: "This procedure accepts as input a RAW, BLOB or BFILE compressed string, verifies it to be a valid compressed value, uncompresses it using Lempel-Ziv compression algorithm"

Comment: I m trying o implement this with java code running inside DB. Will update how that goes hsortly